# Adding behaviors to models without interference

Tags: modeling, aspect-oriented, behavior

This is my situation:

Models can contain properties which can be models themselves. Each property can have custom behavior, this behavior must be selected through its name (for example: Versionable, Authorizable or something else). Developers must have the ability to add their own behaviors to the list with available behaviors.

Each behavior is implemented in a class, but here is the catch: A model can implement zero or more behaviors. How to be sure that behaviors are being executed in the right manner (e.g. sequence) without breaking up things from other behaviors.

I first would suggest that there would be list of supported behaviours, but since a programmer does not know for sure which other behaviors are possible, this does not seem to be a good option.

Comment: You need to ***codify*** your constraints so that they can be checked at the right time by your program.  This could be as simple as a dependency graph.

Answer (score 1):

Change type as valid behaviors change. [Here's an example](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/wizard-design-pattern.html).

Internal Domain Specific Languages (iDSL) allow for just what you describe. They can be easy to use but are a bit of work to create. They work by changing their return type with each call thus limiting what is valid to call next.